# Removing white space added by CreateTextNode after Removechildnode

Tags: c#, xml, c#-4.0, c#-2.0

I am Adding Some X  elements to Root element using (We are using .Net 2.0)

```
xnode.AppendChild(parentINode);
xnode.AppendChild(config.CreateTextNode("\r\n"));
//then removeing all added elements using 
xnode.ParentNode.RemoveChild(xnode);
```

This Will Add a whitespace, I want to remove whitespace that were addedd by adding elements, while removing the childnode.

My original file looks as below:

```
  <c123:Images State="ARASU">
  <!-- Names-Images -->
 </c123:Images>
```

We will Be adding some elements to it :

```
    <c123:Images State="ARASU">
     <!-- Names-Images -->
     <Name place=123>
     <Name place=1234>
     </c123:Images>
```

Then we will delete elements :then it looks as below

```
   <c123:Images State="ARASU">
   <!-- Names-Images -->


    </c123:Images>
```

Here we are getting number of white spaces equal to number of elements added, we want to remove/Avoid the white space created after deleting child nodes.
Thanks & Regards,
Channabasappa M

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this extension method :

```
    public static void RemoveEmptyElementsAndWhiteSpaces(this XDocument document)
    {
        if(null == document)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("document");

        document.Descendants()
            .Where(e => e.IsEmpty || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(e.Value))
            .Remove();
    }
```

Edit : if you are using the XmlDocument class, maybe you can set the PreserveWhiteSpace property to false ?

Comment: Thank you, we are using .Net 2.0 i think System.Linq will not support in it.

Comment: Thank you i tried with reserveWhiteSpace=false, it did not worked.

Comment: schglurps: I have updated my questions with outputs please let me know your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I Did Just Traversing to XML tag then Removed whitespace with checking

```
    //Removing whitespace created 

   if (xnode.NextSibling != null && xnode.NextSibling.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Whitespace)
      {
            xnode.ParentNode.RemoveChild(xnode.NextSibling);
      }
```